# Auto Login after register

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone help me with auto register after login please, Here is my register script...

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array ('email', 'username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'last_name');
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
        $errors [] = 'ALL fields MUST be filled out correctly';
        break 1;
    }
}

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if (user_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
        $errors [] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use.';   
    }
            if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['email']) == true) {
            $errors[] = 'Your email must not contain any spaces';

    }
            if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors [] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already in use.';   
    }
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
            $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces';

    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6)  {
    $errors[] = 'Your password must be in between 6-24 characters long';
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST ['password_again']) {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match';
    }

}
}
?>
```

This code only registers the user and I want it to login aswell, Can you not rate this badly please

Comment: How do you perform logins? We cannot help without knowing that part.

Comment: For future reference, _asking_ to refrain from downvoting is an almost certain way to get downvotes...  A better strategy would be to say "If I can offer more information or improve this question, please let me know what else you need..."

Comment: I am guessing that after this code you are actually doing the registration because this code looks like it's only checking whether all registration information is valid. But once you register, just set up a session for them automatically using the given username/password with whatever system you use for "login".

Comment: I login using the email and password

Comment: actually this code only checks your $_POST and makes error, but does not either save the user or login the user. if you'll provide  the registration part maybe you'll understand yourself how to do the login part?

Comment: @user2055453 Not enough. We need to see how you perform the login query, how you store the session, etc.

Comment: It does actually save/register people I need help with the code to auto create a session after user is registered but I am not bright with code right now because I am learning php whilst making this website

Comment: `preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['email'])` is the same as `false !== strpos($_POST['email'], ' ')` ... but don't you validate the address as well?

Comment: I have more of the script in another file which holds the register function,

Comment: This is a terrible question. You show code that's mostly irrelevant - validating the form fields - and don't show us where you register the user, or where you're trying to log them in. Nobody can answer this without a crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

End of your registration script

```
//include your login validation
if(empty($errors)){
   //User->login(); or anything you use for validating logins
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform logins you generally will need to create a cookie for the user (using PHP's setcookie function) and initialize the session variables that hold their user data (like their username).

This link will show you how to use setcookie() http://php.net/setcookie

As for session variables, they can be set arbitrarily like this:

$_SESSION['username'] = "Admin";

Creating a **secure** login script takes some time, so I would suggest working with forms already out there and just adapt them to your needs. For it to be truly secure, you need to do rigorous sanity checks for database input, secure login and form posting using checksums, and a lot of other factors to account for.

Comment: I sanitize all my data ect....

Comment: I have a working login script also, I just need to do it so it automaticaly Logs the user in after they have registered instead of having to type in their email and password again

Comment: In that case, simply give the user a cookie and set the $_SESSION variables.  Then use those session variables to display the username and any other information pertinent.